# Set grammatical sequence UWP

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, speech-recognition, grammar

I recreated a minimal example from GitHub's SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis from the Scenario_SRGSConstraint.xaml.cs scenario using the grammar I created in an xml file called grammar.

What I would like to solve would be the sequence of words with which to start the action. I recreated the model so that I could choose two colors: red and green for a rectangle background.

Now what I have to say (I will use words in Italian by necessity) to start the action after pressing the button I must pronounce the color first, between red and green and then background to start the action.

I would like to be able to pronounce the background first (then sfondo) and then the color (then rosso o verde), I tried in various ways to modify the grammar.xml several times without success.

I wanted to ask at this point what changes I have to make to start the action by saying the sentence for example: red background or green background ... so as to pronounce the word background (then sfondo) first and then red or green (then rosso o verde) word.

Finally I would like to ask if I need to change only the grammar.xml or even the Code Behind.

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
    private IAsyncOperation<SpeechRecognitionResult> recognitionOperation;
    private ResourceContext speechContext;
    private ResourceMap speechResourceMap;

    private Dictionary<string, Color> colorLookup = new Dictionary<string, Color>
    {
        { "COLOR_RED",   Colors.Red }, {"COLOR_GREEN",  Colors.Green}

    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        bool permissionGained = await AudioCapturePermissions.RequestMicrophonePermission();
        if (permissionGained)
        {
            Language speechLanguage = SpeechRecognizer.SystemSpeechLanguage;
            string langTag = speechLanguage.LanguageTag;
            speechContext = ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
            speechContext.Languages = new string[] { langTag };

            speechResourceMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("LocalizationSpeechResources");

            await InitializeRecognizer();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        if (speechRecognizer != null)
        {
            if (speechRecognizer.State != SpeechRecognizerState.Idle)
            {
                if (recognitionOperation != null)
                {
                    recognitionOperation.Cancel();
                    recognitionOperation = null;
                }
            }

            speechRecognizer.StateChanged -= SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged;

            this.speechRecognizer.Dispose();
            this.speechRecognizer = null;
        }
    }

    private async Task InitializeRecognizer()
    {
        if (speechRecognizer != null)
        {
            speechRecognizer.StateChanged -= SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged;

            this.speechRecognizer.Dispose();
            this.speechRecognizer = null;
        }

        try
        {


            string languageTag = SpeechRecognizer.SystemSpeechLanguage.LanguageTag;
            StorageFile grammarFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///grammar.xml"));

            speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(SpeechRecognizer.SystemSpeechLanguage);

            speechRecognizer.StateChanged += SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged;

            SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint grammarConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint(grammarFile);
            speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(grammarConstraint);
            SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult compilationResult = await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { string message = ex.Message; }
    }

    private async void SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged(SpeechRecognizer sender, SpeechRecognizerStateChangedEventArgs args)
    {

    }


    private async void RecognizeWithoutUI_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            recognitionOperation = speechRecognizer.RecognizeAsync();
            SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await recognitionOperation;
            if (speechRecognitionResult.Status == SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
            {
                HandleRecognitionResult(speechRecognitionResult);
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TaskCanceledException caught while recognition in progress (can be ignored):");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses the result from the speech recognizer to change the colors of the shapes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recoResult">The result from the recognition event</param>
    private void HandleRecognitionResult(SpeechRecognitionResult recoResult)
    {
        // Check the confidence level of the recognition result.
        if (recoResult.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.High ||
        recoResult.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Medium)
        {
            if (recoResult.SemanticInterpretation.Properties.ContainsKey("KEY_BACKGROUND") && recoResult.SemanticInterpretation.Properties["KEY_BACKGROUND"][0].ToString() != "...")
            {
                string backgroundColor = recoResult.SemanticInterpretation.Properties["KEY_BACKGROUND"][0].ToString();
                colorRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(getColor(backgroundColor));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a color object from the passed in string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="colorString">The name of the color</param>
    private Color getColor(string colorString)
    {
        Color newColor = Colors.Transparent;

        if (colorLookup.ContainsKey(colorString))
        {
            newColor = colorLookup[colorString];
        }

        return newColor;
    }
```

grammar.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<grammar xml:lang="it-IT" root="colorChooser"
tag-format="semantics/1.0" version="1.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">

  <rule id="background_Color">
    <item>
      <item>
        <ruleref uri="#color"/>
      </item>
      sfondo
    </item>
  </rule>

  <rule id="colorChooser">
    <one-of>

      <item>
        <item>
          <ruleref uri="#background_Color"/>
          <tag> out.KEY_BACKGROUND=rules.latest(); </tag>
        </item>
      </item>

    </one-of>
  </rule>

  <rule id="color">
    <one-of>

      <item>
        rosso <tag> out="COLOR_RED"; </tag>
      </item>
      <item>
        verde <tag> out="COLOR_GREEN"; </tag>
      </item>

    </one-of>
  </rule>

</grammar>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

--Update--

With this setting it is wrong ... I also tried to set playCommands with items that have exit tags but it does not run correctly (I update my post to highlight my test with your suggestion) The problem is that " out.KEY_BACKGROUND = rules.latest (); " must be inserted somewhere to start the action because in the code behind it is executed through this key: KEY_BACKGROUND.

Codice grammar.xml provato da me con il tuo suggerimento:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <grammar xml:lang="it-IT" root="playCommands"
tag-format="semantics/1.0" version="1.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">
    ​
    <rule id="background_Color">
      <item>
        sfondo​
      </item>​
    </rule>​
    ​
    <rule id="playCommands">
      <item>
        <ruleref uri="#background_Color" />​
      </item>
      <item>
        <ruleref uri="#color" />​
        <tag> out.KEY_BACKGROUND=rules.latest(); </tag>
      </item>
      
      
    </rule>​
    ​
    <rule id="color">
      <one-of>
        <item>
          rosso <tag> out="COLOR_RED"; </tag>​
        </item>​
        <item>
          verde <tag> out="COLOR_GREEN"; </tag>​
        </item>​
      </one-of>​
    </rule>
    ​
  </grammar>
```

--Update1--

I tried your code and I think that the grammar.xml logic is correct, but in the code behind it gives me an error here:

```
recognitionOperation = speechRecognizer.RecognizeAsync();
```

In the method RecognizeWithoutUI_Click

And the error is this:

> The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Here is the complete project: [Test Grammar UWP](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjedWjxtK_C81EdOtZg61sH71QyM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to the elements must be listed in the order that the user will speak the command, you can create a top-level rule element that references both the background and color rules to create a flexible collection of commands, And set the command to be the root, like below:

grammar.xml:

```
<grammar xml:lang="it-IT" root="playCommands"
tag-format="semantics/1.0" version="1.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">
    ​
    <rule id="background_Color">
      <item>
        sfondo​
      </item>​
    </rule>​
    ​
    <rule id="playCommands">
      <ruleref uri="#background_Color" />​
      <ruleref uri="#color" />​
    </rule>​
    ​
    <rule id="color">
      <one-of>
        <item>
          rosso <tag> out="COLOR_RED"; </tag>​
        </item>​
        <item>
          verde <tag> out="COLOR_GREEN"; </tag>​
        </item>​
      </one-of>​
    </rule>
    ​
  </grammar>
```

**Update:**

If you want to use "out.KEY_BACKGROUND = rules.latest();" You just need to change the position of the `sfondo` and `<ruleref uri="#color"/>`. In this case, it will execute the **backgroundColor** first and then the **color**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<grammar xml:lang="it-IT" root="colorChooser"
tag-format="semantics/1.0" version="1.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">

  <rule id="background_Color">
    <item>
      sfondo
      <item>
        <ruleref uri="#color"/>
      </item>
    </item>
  </rule>

  <rule id="colorChooser">
        <item>
          <ruleref uri="#background_Color"/>
          <tag> out.KEY_BACKGROUND=rules.latest(); </tag>
        </item>
  </rule>

  <rule id="color">
    <one-of>

      <item>
        rosso <tag> out="COLOR_RED"; </tag>
      </item>
      <item>
        verde <tag> out="COLOR_GREEN"; </tag>
      </item>

    </one-of>
  </rule>

</grammar>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can try the updated method.

Comment: I inserted a link with the modified project with your suggestions at the end of my post

Comment: The error means unable to compile grammar, it seems to have some formatting problems in your grammar file. So it is recommended that you can directly copy my whole updated grammar.xml to cover the content of yours. And I tested, it worked. In addition, please make sure that the language you are currently using is the same as the one set in your xml:lang.

Comment: Thanks following your instructions the grammar.xml file works correctly. Thanks!